# Assign default user role when user registers to website with flask-user

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to assign a default user role to newly registered accounts. I'm using the flask-user plugin(http://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). In the flask-user documentation they use this code to manually assign a user role to a new account:

```
if not User.query.filter(User.email == 'admin@example.com').first():
    user = User(
        email='admin@example.com',
        email_confirmed_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        password=user_manager.hash_password('Password1'),
    )
    user.roles.append(Role(name='Admin'))
    user.roles.append(Role(name='Agent'))
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```

But how can this be done automatically when the user registers?

Answer (score 2):

Use signals. `user_registered` signal is emitted after successful user registration. Its subscriber can do every necessary initialization:

```
from flask_user import user_registered

@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def _after_user_registered_hook(sender, user, user_invite, **extra):
    role = Role.query.filter_by(name='Agent').one()
    user.roles.append(role)
    app.user_manager.db_adapter.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks @vvch, you made some insight for me to do it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to assign a default role is to modify the UserRoles class, adding a default value to the role_id colum.

```
class UserRoles(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_roles'
    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer(),
        primary_key=True
    )
    user_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer(),
        db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE')
    )
    role_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer(),
        db.ForeignKey('roles.id',
        ondelete='CASCADE'),
        default=1
    )
```

[The original class from the docs here.](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_app.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the newest [flask-user docs](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html) you can use this. It helped me solve the problem. the import is .. important.

```
from flask_user.signals import user_registered

@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def _after_registration_hook(sender, user, **extra):
    print('user is registered', sender, user)
```